# Javascript: Promise returning instantly, rather than waiting for asynchronous process to finish

Tags: javascript, authentication, promise, httprequest

Essentially when i call my function getToken() it should return the bearer + token from the api.

The problem I have is that due to the asynchronous process that happens, the data is not returned instantly; so in reading the following resource:

- [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

My understanding is that I need to return my response in the form of a promise, and set a timeout to ensure that the return accounts for the time it takes for the server to send back my request in the form of a response.

```
var request = require('request-promise');
var time = require('timers');
class Auth {
 getToken() {
   let options = {
     method: 'POST',
     uri: 'https://example.com/service/ep',
     body: {
       username: 'someUser',
       password: 'somePass'
     },
     json: true
   }
  request(options)
    .then(function (body) {
      // console.log(body)
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        time.setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(body)
        },3000)
    });
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    return err
  });
 }
}
module.exports = new Auth
```

Unfortunately when i run my program in the node repel, it returns nothing and it does not appear to wait; of course when i log my response 'console.log(body)', it appears meaning there must be something wrong with how i'm returning my promise; i'm quite new to the likes of promises.

Could use with a second pair of eyes.

Comment: How are you calling `getToken()`? Are you using `.then()` when you call it properly? And forget timeouts like that, they're not what you need and would be very fragile.

Comment: The aim is to use getToken() to return the bearer token, so that i can make other requests to test the API. I figure the timeouts are probably not the best approach.

Comment: You definitely shouldn't be relying on a setTimeout, the promise is supposed to resolve (and your then called) when the response is received. I'm assuming this is for node otherwise I would question why you're not using whatwg-fetch?

Comment: Because in theory your code seems like it should work (albeit with a 3 second delay), could you post the part where you try to call that function?

Comment: At the moment i just call the function in the node repel (command line): node like so: 
var data = require('file');
data.getToken();

Do I need to do something with the call?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't wait? You don't do anything with the result after the timeout has resolved the promise.

Comment: You forgot to `return` the promise, i.e. `return request(options)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My understanding is that I need to return my response in the form of a promise, and set a timeout to ensure that the return accounts for the time it takes for the server to send back my request in the form of a response.

No. You need to return a promise (`request` already gives you one) and then the code you return the promise to needs to *expect* a promise (and call `then()` on it to get the data).

You don't need any time delays.

---

```
var request = require('request-promise');
var time = require('timers');
class Auth {
 getToken() {
   let options = {
     method: 'POST',
     uri: 'https://example.com/service/ep',
     body: {
       username: 'someUser',
       password: 'somePass'
     },
     json: true
   }
  return request(options);
 }
}
module.exports = new Auth
```

---

```
const auth = require("Auth");
auth.getToken().then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: I misunderstood how to use promises, at least I thought I was handling it in the first function. since then i've written another function to try and handle the response.


`makeAnotherRequest() {
    let token; 
    this.getToken().then(function (data) {
      token = data;
      console.log('response from the server: ', data);
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log('error ', error)
    });
    request.get('https://example.com/service/ep/207', {
      'auth': {
        'bearer': `${token}`
      }
    });
  }`
currently working on handling error case.